# Filtered aggregation query error

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to run a filtered aggregation like below but getting error.
**"Unknown key for a START_OBJECT in [associations]: [disabledDate]**. Can anyone review the query and suggest any changes required.

STEPS in the query:
 1. Query all documents with versionDate less than or equal to the given
    date.
 2. Aggregate on Id.
 3. Run a subaggregation top hits query with missing disabledDate filter.
 4. apply post filter for missing disabledDate.

```
{
       "query": {
          "bool": {
             "must": [
                {
                   "range": {
                      "versionDate": {
                         "from": null,
                         "to": "2016-05-25T20:53:22.742Z",
                         "include_lower": false,
                         "include_upper": true
                      }
                   }
                },
                {
                   "terms": {
                      "domainId": [
                         "yy"
                      ]
                   }
                },
                {
                   "terms": {
                      "termId": [
                         "rr"
                      ]
                   }
                }
             ]
          }
       },
       "aggregations": {
          "associations": {
             "terms": {
                "field": "id",
                "size": 0,
                "execution_hint": "global_ordinals_low_cardinality",
                "order": {
                   "_term": "asc"
                },
                "disabledDate": {
                   "filters": {
                      "missing": {
                         "field": "disbaledDate"
                      }
                   },
                   "aggregations": {
                      "top": {
                         "top_hits": {
                            "size": 1,
                            "_source": {
                               "includes": [],
                               "excludes": []
                            },
                            "sort": [
                               {
                                  "versionDate": {
                                     "order": "desc"
                                  }
                               }
                            ]
                         }
                      }
                   }
                }
             }
          }
       },
       "post_filter": {
          "missing": {
             "field": "disabledDate"
          }
       }
    }
```